# Internet Explorer manipulation

Tags: internet-explorer

I want an icon on the desktop when clicked opens-up  a web application hosted locally. The application should open only on internet explorer as this application is intended only to work with internet explorer. While the application opens-up, IE has to be  manipulated such that the address bar is disabled, tabbed browsing is disabled, menu bars and all other toolbars are disable and the navigation menus are disabled?

The applications I am talking is explicitly built on php and mysql. Is there a way to get around all these?

Comment: this is probably better suited to superuser.com, but as a hint try looking at IE's "kiosk mode"

Comment: Isn't there any other way out rather than kiosk mode? And yeah one portion remains unanswered...how to make the application work only with internet explorer? ..Regards.

Comment: What's wrong with kiosk mode?  And if you want it to work only with IE, add some code to your app to check the user-agent and serve an error page if anything other than IE is used.

Comment: No nothing is wrong with kisok mode but there are still limitations and kisok mode can be tweaked easily. So I thought if there is a much better way around. Other than that kisok mode is alright.

Comment: IT would obviously be better if you had the deliberation of setting the window size rather than the full screen. I dont seem to find a way to set the window size in kisok mode.

Answer (score 0):

Look at kiosk mode maybe?

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/commandlineswitches.php#IE